# Slow network between host (Windows 7) and guest (Ubuntu 10.04 LTS)

Tags: networking, virtualbox, connection

I'm using VirtualBox on my Windows 7 (64-bit) laptop, in order to manage 3 Ubuntu 10.04 VMs  for web development. One is 32-bit, the two others are 64-bit.

For the past two days, when I try to reach my guest-hosted website from the host OS, I'm experiencing slow network speeds. When I look at my Firebug > Network tab I see that the main files require between and 5 and 10 sec to load. I got this message after logging in:

> system information disabled due to load higher than 1.0.

I see this message more as a symptom rather than my real problem.

The network problem has reached all three Ubuntu guest OSs.

Here's my config:

**HOST**

- *Config:*

  - Windows 7
  - 8GB RAM
  - SSD harddrive (6 months)
  - VirtualBox 4.0.10

    - Host-only adapters configured in virtualbox > file > preferences > network :

      - ip: 192.168.20.1
      - netmask: 255.255.255.0
      - DHCP active:

        - Server address: 192.168.20.100
        - Server Mask: 255.255.255.0
        - Lower address bound: 192.168.20.101
        - Upper address bound: 192.168.20.200
- *Network :*

  - My wired connection is configured with the *virtualbox bridged networking driver* active in my card advanced properties

    IP: 192.168.0.2

    Gateway: 192.168.0.254

    *DNS from Free (French ISP) :*

    - IP: 212.27.40.241
    - IP: 212.27.40.240

My windows hosts config file contains redirections to the bridged card like this:

```
192.168.0.XXX (vm ip)       vmName www.domaine-on-this-vm.com
```

When I reach my guest hosted website from the host and I look at my Firebug > Network tab, I see that the guest takes between 0 and 10 s to respond.

**GUEST** (1 @ 32-bit and 2 @ 64-bit, so I don't think number of bits matters)

- 1 processor
- 512 ram
- *acceleration:*

  - vt-x/amd-v = ok
  - nested paging = ok
  - pae/nx = ok
- *Network :*

  - adapter 1 = bridged network (intel pro/1000 mt desktop)

    - IP: 192.168.0.xxx (vm ip staticaly fixed in /etc/network/interfaces (see below)
  - adapter 1 = bridged network (intel pro/1000 mt desktop)

    - IP: 192.168.20.xxx (vm ip fixed via dhcp in /etc/network/interfaces (see below)
  - File /etc/network/interfaces

    - ```
      # This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
      # and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

      # The loopback network interface
      auto lo
      iface lo inet loopback

      # The primary network interface
      auto eth0
      iface eth0 inet static
      address 192.168.0.21
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      gateway 192.168.0.254
      auto eth1
      iface eth1 inet dhcp
      ```
  - File /etc/hosts:

    - 127.0.0.1 vmName www.domaine-on-this-vm.com
- *Software installed:*

  - apache2
  - php5
  - samba
  - openssh
  - compass (on ruby, css framework development)
  - svn

Everything was doing fine during 5 months with those configs/software before the bug begun.

**Facing this, I've tried to:**

- raise the amount of RAM and the number of processors
- re-install a fresher version of virtualbox and an older one
- create a new VM with the same .vdi
- change the adapter type from Intel pro/1000 desktop to anothers
- tried different network interfaces config file alternatives (no dhcp / dhcp)
- tried to nslookup my ISP provider's DNS automaticaly filled in the /etc/resolv.conf file (and it's OK)

...but with no effects.

One more symptom is that during my debug process, I've rebooted my VMs a lot, and I got a disk issue message durinng boot: "your disk haven't been checked for last 24 boots, check forced" or something like that, then it tells me a short message that I can't read, and only then I got the login field.

I'm really new to all Linux things (and not english fluent...). I can't see if it's a network issue or a disk issue, please let me know which commands might help me to dig into this?

Answer (score 1):

I've found out my problem: My laptop battery management plan.

Since I've had to work on a train last week end, I've tried some network configurations to be able to access my VM without network (no host-only at this moment) and this is why I was looking in that direction.

In the end, it was just because I've turned on the "economic mode" on my laptop battery.